# Adding a border to circle object fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I'm trying to add a border to a circle. The only round about way I can think of is by adding another circle underneath it. Is there a better way?

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9mqqh3of/4/

PS: having trouble centering it too.

HTML:

```
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Javascript:

```
var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c');

let radius = 20;
let radius1 = 10;

let circle = new fabric.Circle({
  fill: "green",
  hoverCursor: "pointer",
  left: 20 - radius,
  opacity: 1,
  radius,
  selectable: false,
  strokeWidth: 5,
  strokeColor: "white",
  top: 20 - radius
});   

let circle1 = new fabric.Circle({
  fill: "red",
  hoverCursor: "pointer",
  left: 20 - radius1,
  opacity: 1,
  radius: radius1,
  top: 20 - radius1
}); 

canvas.add(circle);
canvas.add(circle1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [stroke](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#stroke) for stroke color and [strokeWidth](http://fabricjs.com/docs/fabric.Object.html#strokeWidth) for width of stroke.

***DEMO***

```js
let canvas = new fabric.Canvas('canvas');
let circle = new fabric.Circle({
  fill: "green",
  hoverCursor: "pointer",
  left: 20,
  opacity: 1,
  radius:100,
  selectable: false,
  strokeWidth: 15,
  stroke: "red",
  top: 20
});   
canvas.add(circle)
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kangax/fabric.js/master/dist/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
```